# Getting error of unable to load Newtonsoft.Json.Dll as my Web API project already contain reference of Newtonsoft json dll which is older

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, json.net

Getting error of unable to load Newtonsoft.Json.Dll as my Web API project already contain reference of Newtonsoft json dll which is older.

I have added my DLLs (which I have written and one of the dll refer to newtonsoft dll). When I run project and hit request to my web service it shows error of unable to load newtonsoft dll.

For this I removed the existing newtonsoft reference and added the newer from my set of dlls but still getting same error.

Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: Where ever you have used reference of Newtonsoft.Json.Dll., remove from that and add new version. and build the solution.

Comment: Where I have used the reference it is newer version, but the already added reference (automatically came when I create Web API project) is old version. Existing reference - 5.6.0, Newer version which I have added is 10.0.1....

Comment: You are using n-tier architecture application?

Comment: No, simply took one Web API solution and trying to add my DLLs in it. Now I have added Newtonsoft 9.0.. in Web API project through Nuget but still it is showing error Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Comment: Open your project Visual Studio at Administration rights. go to Solution explorer and right click go to properities. Open References tab in left side. Remove your newtonsoft.json. and add new version. then delete your bin and obj folders. then you build your solution. and check it

Answer (score 0):

It depends on kind of errors but sometimes it seems that you have to delete build folder : ***obj*** and ***bin***. and after re-run your project.